# Publish a git repository to a subfolder of another git repository

Tags: git, azure, github

On Azure it is possible connect an Azure website to a git repository. All changes committed to that git repository are deployed to the Azure web site. I would like to achieve the following:

Connect a git repository "main" to an Azure site, and have multiple other git repositories "publish" to a sub folder in the "main" git repositories, so the code will be automatically deployed to the Azure web site.

Comment: have you tried git submodules?

Comment: Don't know much about git, so didn't know about it. Thanks for the pointer. I will dive into http://blog.jacius.info/git-submodule-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Hanselman did a post on his blog recently about publish to more than one website from one git repository, maybe it could help you http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingTWOWebsitesToWindowsAzureFromOneGitRepository.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This post from Hanselman should help.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingTWOWebsitesToWindowsAzureFromOneGitRepository.aspx

The basic idea is to push your sub folder to the root of the remote git repository.

Comment: The Hanselman post is the other way round: have a single git repository, push one project to website1 nd another project to website2. I would like to have multiple git repositories to come together into a single azure website so I don't have to have a new azure website for each project. The different play projects can co-exist in a single azure website.